# How do I copy a script from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to copy an existing script, which I did not write, into my existing spreadsheet.  The script is called "SaveBack", and can be found here:  https://docs.google.com/a/levelgroup.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Agcb8bUVVOOodHhoV3BrRGZ6UEdSYnVLSEk3bllxRnc#gid=1.

My existing spreadsheet is too complex (it has many other spreadsheets that link to it) to copy all of its sheets into the spreadsheet that contains the script.  I have already copied the SaveBack editor sheet template sheet to my main spreadsheet, but I can't figure out how to copy the SaveBack script that goes along with it into my spreadsheet.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open the save back script, select the script text, copy it, go to your sheet, create a new script (blank template), paste the script you copied into your new script, name is SaveBack (assuming it's a project), check the triggers on the original script and make sure your triggers match, and you should be good to go.  You will have to change any sheet, document, or other string ID's to match your files' Id's, but that isn't too bad.

I do this sort of thing all of the time when I'm migrating things back and forth between my work and personal account.  You could also create a copy of the other person's spreadsheet that you linked above, and it will move the script over with it. Then you can go to the script and get the project key to use it as library in your own scripts.  Since you're using your copy as the library, you don't have to worry about someone else changing the script and breaking your functionality.